# Combine multiple form input into key pair value array and add dimension to value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I have following `$_POST` array :

```
Array
(
    [fileName] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8.png
            [1] => 2_OnClick_OK.jpg
        )

    [fileLink] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
            [1] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
        )

    [Submit] => Submit File
)
```

I got the above output after execution of following statement:

```
print_r($_POST); die; // Code to print the $_POST array
```

Now from the above `$_POST` array I've to create a new desired array which should be structured as follows after printing it:

```
Array
        (
            [8.png] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
                )
            [2_OnClick_OK.jpg]
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
                )   

        )
```

For this I tried following code.

```
 $request_Arr = array_combine ( $_POST['fileName'], $_POST['fileLink'] );
```

After execution of above code if I print the array `$request_Arr` it prints following output:

```
 Array ( 
    [8.png] => filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd 
    [2_OnClick_OK.jpg] => filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ 
)
```

So my issue is it's not generating the `[0]` index key for inner array. I want the new array with `[0]` index key present as follows :

```
Array
 (
    [8.png] => Array
    (
        [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zZ993JyCT9KafUtXAzYd
    )
    [2_OnClick_OK.jpg]
    (
        [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1w3cKCW1TMmytb7md3XQ
    )   
)
```

Can someone please correct my mistake and help me in creating an array in desired format?

N.B.:- For demonstration purpose only I've taken two elements. In actual scenario there could be hundreds of such elements. So please consider an optimum and efficient way to get this output array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way would be to map all of the link to add another nest dimension, then finally combine.

```
$fileLink = array_map(function($link){ return array($link); }, $_POST['fileLink']);
$request_Arr = array_combine ( $_POST['fileName'], $fileLink );
```

Or if you can modify the markup and it looks something like this, and prefer not touching the original array:

```
<input type="text" name="fileName[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="fileLink[][]" value="" /> // adds another nest
```

Then combine outright:

```
$request_Arr = array_combine ( $_POST['fileName'], $_POST['fileLink'] );
```

Comment: Just the slight change you suggested into HTML did the job for me. It really worked superbly and producing the new array in desired format. I just have one last query please answer it. Now the code is working fine for two or more such input controls but will it work when there will be single such entry available on form? Please answer my query.

Comment: @user2839497 yes that a very important note to remember, its important that they must also be perfectly aligned all the time, if there is one slight mismatch array combine might fail.

Comment: @user2839497 if i would create such grouping structure i would do it just like this, http://pastebin.com/1NB0Lvmg

Comment: @user2839497 if you want to go this route, (i'm not good at js btw), if these fields can be further added dynamically you could add another one to add that numeric index for the grouping http://jsfiddle.net/utsdteom/

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use a foreach loop in order to construct the new array:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST['fileName'] as $key => $value) {
    $array[$value] = array($_POST['fileLink'][$key]);
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>';
```